# How can I GET an API with ruby if it's behind Cloudflare's Anti DDos protection

Tags: ruby, curl, cloudflare

I was trying to scrape this api, but when i used Net::HTTP.get, it returned the cloudflare page asking me to wait for 5 seconds while it checks my browser.

I looked it up, and there's a module for python and for node.js, but none for ruby. Is this possible with maybe an argument to Net::HTTP or using curl?

Answer (score 0):

You could try specifying a user agent perhaps:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(url)
http.request_get(URL, {'User-Agent' =>'whatever'})
```

Comment: I couldnt get user agent to set so i found another answer that said try open-uri, and now its throwing an exception with http status 503, which is a good start, but didn't help fix it. from what i read, javascript and cookies are required.